# I don't know how to communicate with other scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Player script. I have the variables on there

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    float horimove;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject thrown;
    public bool win;
```

On my other script (I'm making a game where you instantiate spheres into a hole and win.)

```
public class spheresciprt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Player pscript;
    public GameObject player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        pscript = player.GetComponent<Player>();
    }
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("win"))
        {
            pscript.win = true;

        }
    }
```

However pscript.win doesn't change. The bool always stays false but I want the player to win after the sphere hits the trigger in the hole I want it to go to. I tried different computers. The same thing happened in different games I think so I'm probably just missing something.

Comment: First, are the 2 script on the same gameobject?

Comment: Are you sure, that the (trigger) collision is detected and the event/condition is fired accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your script:

```
public class spheresciprt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Player pscript;
    public GameObject player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        pscript = player.GetComponent<Player>();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("win"))
        {
            pscript.win = true;

        }
    }
}
```

It sets pscript to the **current** values in Player script. This is the problem, because it is setting a variable to the current values, and you want access to the component. You could change this by, just replace all of the pscript variables with `player.GetComponent<Player>()`. There are other ways of doing this. You could, at the end of `OnTriggerEnter`, add this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   ...
   player.GetComponent<Player>() = pscript;
}
```

In both of these solutions you fix it. In one, you re-apply the variable. In the other, you are changing the component directly. Which is what you want, because you have pscript as an instance of player script, not the player script that is attached to player.

Comment: Its inverted in the trigger method.

Comment: This `player.GetComponent<Player>() = pscript;` makes no sense. Also `OnTriggerEnter` without the mandatory `Collider` parameter will never get called

Comment: Why doesn’t it make sense? I thought you could do that.

Comment: The component is of type `Player`, and I am setting it to another type `Player`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the collision is detected. You can easily do something like

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
   Debug.Log("Pass1");
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("win"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hey, it worked!");
    }
}
```

in the OnTriggerEnter to check that.

If the collision is NOT detected, make sure there are colliders on all the affected GameObjects, as well as a RigidBody component on the sphere. Also, make sure that the collider is marked as Trigger. If you still have an issue with that, we will need to see your inspector to figure it out.

If the collision IS detected... Well, start by making sure that you have assigned the proper tag on the hole. Then, make sure that the player GameObject is actually called "Player" (since you are trying to find it by name) and that it has the script you are trying to get on the object you actually find (and not on one of its children). I hope that works, because I can't see anything else seriously flawed at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change

if (gameObject.CompareTag("win"))

to

if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("win"))

or just add the rigidbody to both player and other object.
does the other object have "win" tag?